# Create a gradient background that looks like two bars

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I would like to create a background that appears to have two progress bars as in the picture:
[image]

I can easily achieve one progress bar with linear-gradient, yet is there any possibility to split the background in half and let both stop at a specific percentage?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style> 
      #example1 {
         background-color: transparent;
         background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #eceddc 25%, transparent 25%),
         linear-gradient(180deg, #eceddc 50%, transparent 25%),
         linear-gradient(90deg, #eceddc 50%, transparent 25%); 
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="example1">
     <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below:

```css
#example1 {
  background: 
      linear-gradient(#eceddc 0 0) top    left,
      linear-gradient(#eceddc 0 0) bottom left;
  background-size:
    80% 30%, /* width height of the first bar  */
    40% 70%; /* width height of the second bar */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, both bars do not cover exactly half of the height. The top bar has just approx. one third of the height of the one on the bottom

Comment: @mnist you can adjust like you want, I simply used random value to show how to control them. Simply make the height 50% for both

Comment: Ah Indeed! Sorry, I missed this point. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

If you want the same result as the picture, you should use the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#example1 {
background-color: transparent;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #eceddc 75%, white 25%),
linear-gradient(to right, #eceddc 25%, white 25%);
background-position: right top, right bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="example1">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. This looks exactly like the trick I was looking for. Wasnt aware of the fact that one can provide multiple arguments to each background property.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two DIVs and style them with the gradients that make this BG image you want. Then add them as children to the containing div that holds the text elements. Then set the text elements to `position: relative` with a `z-index` of 10.

Now, being that this element may move on the page, you can use Javascript to get the position of the parent element using a handler function. Then set up two `eventListeners`, one for `load` and the other for `scroll`. Call on the handler function with the listeners and move the two BG elements to the position of the parent text element both on load and on scroll.

***EDIT:*** *Used JS to get the height and width of the text elements div, `(offsetHeight & offsetWidth)` and set the height/width of each BG div according to the height of the text div. This makes it more dynamic.*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', handler, false);
window.addEventListener('scroll', handler, false);
let exOne = document.getElementById('example1');
let exTwo = document.getElementById('example2');
let exThree = document.getElementById('example3');

function handler(event) {

  function getOffset(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      left: rect.left + window.scrollX,
      top: rect.top + window.scrollY
    };
  }
  exTwo.style.top = getOffset(exOne).top + "px";
  exTwo.style.left = getOffset(exOne).left + "px";
  exTwo.style.height = exOne.offsetHeight + "px";
  exTwo.style.width = exOne.offsetWidth + "px";
  exTwo.style.display = "block";
  exThree.style.top = getOffset(exOne).top + "px";
  exThree.style.left = getOffset(exOne).left + "px";
  exThree.style.height = exOne.offsetHeight / 1.75 + "px";
  exThree.style.width = exOne.offsetWidth + "px";
  exThree.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#example1 {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 10px;
}

#example1 p,
#example1 h1 {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

#example2 {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #0FF 51%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(to left, #0FF 51%, transparent 25%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /* display none to remove any glitches shown before load 
  add back to block in JS after load*/
  display: none;
}

#example3 {
  background-color: transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eceddc 51%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(to right, #eceddc 51%, transparent 25%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /* display none to remove any glitches shown before load 
  add back to block in JS after load*/
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Scroll down
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="example1">
  <div id="example2"></div>
  <div id="example3"></div>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, the other one lokks much easier and does not require the use of JS. In my actual application I do not have just text on the background which might make things even more complex.

Comment: Yea his is pure css. Best... Don't forget to mark his as accepted ;)